# Runspace broke. (Remoting, WinRM, and Sharepoint )

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-remoting

So first, the following worked fine 3 days ago against the same sharepoint server, works fine against other sharepoint servers in the farm, and after I did something I’ll elaborate on later works fine again.

But for 3 days, I could constantly break my runspace by doing the following

```
$sess = new-pssession –computername $comp –Credential $cred –Authentication CredSSP
```

so far so good

```
Enter-PSSession $sess
```

so far so good

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Still good

I can do 0 or more different Sharepoint gets, like `Get-SPServer`

But then when I do:

```
Get-SPServiceApplication
```

I get:

> Processing data for a remote command
>   failed with the following error
>   message: The WSMan provider host
>   process did not return a proper
>   response. A provider in the host
>   process may have behaved improperly.
>   For more information, see the about
>   _Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

The session kicks back to my main session, and the runspace is broken.

This was consistent, and I’m not sure why. I can run it fine against other servers in the farm, and could run it against this server up until a few days ago

Whats interesting is what "FIXED" it.

So I figured to investigate further I could Terminal Services into the actual machine and run it locally. I did that and it ran locally without error, then AFTER that it ran normally through remoting as well.

Does anybody have a clue what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Really hard to answer that without "rewinding" the machine back into the pre-remotedesktop state and comparing before and after states (registry, network activity, sql, filesystem.) My guess is some kind of one-time initialization process is failing when using credssp delegation, but that's probably pretty obvious.

Comment: the thing is i could continue to do credSSP connections and run other commands that would fail with an auth error if CredSSP wasn't working. But yeah it would be hard to troubleshoot. I am just interested in anybody else has had any experience with this.